# Informal way to describe a path through a JSON structure

Tags: json, path, documentation

I would like to document a path from a root object to some attribute or object in a JSON structure (like an XPath expression). I don't want to dump all the JSON and then attempt to describe a path. Less important, but still a consideration is that I don't want to give the impression that the path represents the entire JSON structure.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what a sensible syntax could look like for this?  As I said, a syntax like XPath's, but only for documentation purposes, is what I have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just describe the path the way you'd access the element, so for example

```
pets.dogs[0].owner.brothers[1].firstName
```

would guide you through a large json object, containing a pets attribute, which contains a dogs attribute with a list of them, get the first element,...

Comment: I have decided to use the mathematical notation for the set of natural numbers when encountering an array. Staying with the above example:

`pets.dogs[N].owner.brothers[N].firstName`